# Perl program parameters

Tags: perl

I am a beginner in programming with perl and csh. I am facing some difficulty understanding code like:

```sh
/some_perl_algorithm.pl -n 166 \ 
    -p "/some_xml.list." \
    -s "" \
    /some_other.list

exit $status
```

1. what do these `-n` `-p` `-s` switches mean?
2. what do these backslashes at the end of the lines (`\`) mean?
3. Is that `/some_perl_algorithm.pl` the same as `perl some_perl_algorithm.pl`?
4. what does this code try to do?

Can anyone help? Or point me some good tutorials?

Comment: Q2. Because this code is written under csh which does not handle multilines, "\" is used to connect different lines.

Comment: You'd need the backslashes under bash as well.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `/some_perl_algorithm.pl` is most likely the same as `perl /some_perl_algorith.pl`. This depends on the first line in that file. See "shebang", i.e. on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

The other questions can't be answered without kowing what `some_perl_algorithm.pl` ìs.  The arguments are passed to the Perl script.

Comment: The backward slashes mean that there is a continuation to that line

Answer (score 0):

perldoc is your friend.  perldoc perlintro to start with

Also:  http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches

- -p means loop the script through all lines listed in the supplied as parameters.
- -n is similar, but overridden by -p in this case.
- -s puts the 166 into the file as a parameter.